# Remove double quotes from value in JSON column

Tags: mysql

I have JSON rows like that

{"Id":"1","eur":1}
{"id": 2, "eur": "1"}
That but 100k row like that and I want to remove the quotes from ids.

I expect { "Id":1,"eur":1}, {"id": 2, "eur": 1}

Comment: I'm curious as to why you are doing this... the result you want is invalid JSON.

Comment: The json column is like that  but 100k rows and 20 more currencies.                             
 {"id": "1", "eur": "2", "usd": 2}
, {"id": "2", "eur": "1", "usd": "2"}
 {"id": "4", "eur": "2", "usd": "12"}
'"id": "5", "eur": 20, "usd": "122"}              I am new on that and i dont know if i can unquote the values not the keys with 1 query i tried with reqexp and the json_unquote(json_extract()) but this works only with one key per time. I know, with out quotes its invalid but the company i worked assigned me that and i am trying to find i way to do it (i am junior dba).

Answer (score 0):

Your second line without quotes is not valid JSON, the original line with quotes is. You can access the values without quotes like this:

```
SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT('{"Id":"Ids","eur":1}', '$.Id'));
```

Comment: Actually I have 15 more field like that in every row and I don't know if is possible to remove all the quotes with one query

Comment: Of course it is possible, just use JSON_UNQUOTE.

Comment: I don't won't to make a select statement. I want to make something like that
Update table name
Set column_name = query

Comment: As I said in my answer, if you remove the quotes the remaining text won't be a valid JSON: https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Yes I know that strings must have quotes but I want to used like int I tried with cast but worked only with one column per time. So I guess my problem is how to convert it from varchar to int-double

Comment: You can use JSON_UNQUOTE in an UPDATE statement.